# How can I check if all rows have the same column value?

Tags: php, mysql

Here's the simple query:

```
SELECT status FROM tbl_pedidos_produtos WHERE status = 4;
```

This, obviously, brings me only the entries whose status equals to 4, but in this manner I can't test if ALL entries have status 4. How can I do something like this?

```
SELECT status FROM tbl_pedidos_produtos WHERE status OF ALL = 4;
```

Comment: Check if any row has not `4` as status.

Comment: You can do a GROUP BY status and see if it returns more than one row

Comment: There are a few different ways you can do this, so I might come back in a couple of days and see all the options that have been proposed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using aggregation.  Here is one way:

```
select (max(status) = 4 and min(status) = 4 and status is not null) as AllSameFlag
from tbl_pedidos_produtos;
```

Another way that might be a bit less obvious:

```
select (count(*) = 0) as AllSameFlag
from tbl_pedidos_produtos
where status <> 4 or status is null
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply, just get `COUNT(*)` of the rows those doesn't have status = 4

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_pedidos_produtos WHERE status != 4;
```

If it's greater than 0, that means you have at least one row which has status != 4.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have null values in there, you can do that in a single query by selecting all distinct status values, counting them, then make sure that adds up to 1. Like this:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `status`) from `tbl_pedidos_produtos`)  = 1;
```

If you do have null values (i.e., a product without a status value for some reason), then you'll need to filter them out first.